# Cloud Function / Firestore: timestampsInSnapshots not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm using Firebase with Firestore and Cloud Function. The problem is that inside my Cloud Function when i get document from Firestore, **the dates fields aren't of type Date nor Timestamp.**

I'm using the following versions:

```
"firebase-admin": "^6.5.0",
"firebase-functions": "^2.1.0",
```

Here's my code to set `timestampsInSnapshots`to true.

```
// file: index.ts    
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();
const firestore = admin.firestore();
const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
firestore.settings(settings);
```

Even with the code above i still have the following warning on the Cloud Functions logs:

> The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change
>   AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK. To hide this warning and ensure your app does
>   not break, you need to add the following code to your app before
>   calling any other Cloud Firestore methods:
>
> const firestore = new Firestore();
>   const settings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true};
>   firestore.settings(settings);

How to make the `timestampsInSnapshots` setting working ? To be able to receive Timestamp object inside Cloud Functions.

Comment: Is that code in your index.js/index.ts?

Comment: Yes, inside the index.ts, and the index.js generated still has the lines.